# Automate AWS EC2 creation using yaml and cloudformation

Tags: amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I am going to automate AWS EC2 instance creation. I have a yaml file which built using cloud formation template. I want to know how do i run this using command line interface.

Comment: Do you have it successfully working if you use CloudFormation via the AWS Management Console? That would be a good first step before you automate it from the command-line.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to upload your template to S3.

create bucket

```
aws s3api create-bucket --bucket cloud-formation-stacks --region us-east-1
```

upload to S3

```
aws s3 sync --delete <template> s3://cloud-formation-stacks
```

create stack

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name mystack 
--template-url <template url> 
--parameters ParameterKey=KeyName,ParameterValue=YOUR_KEY_NAME
```

add your parameters as shown. (vpc, security group, subnet id, tags etc etc)

OR. you can do this viva AWS management console, Services->Cloudformation and upload your template.

Comment: I used following template which was in amazon tutorial

Comment: I used following template which was in amazon tutorial

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-formats.html

Then i saved the file in my local machine as test2.yaml. I used this template to create a EC2 instance using below command
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name myteststack --template-body file:///home/dewmi/test2.yaml

But stack creation is rolled back. Is there anything wrong in the template. Does this keyName should be changed?

Comment: i guess you're new to aws cloud formation. first of all please go through these sample templates
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ec2.html
to successfully create a EC2 you need to define following properties:
1. ImageId 
2. InstanceType
3. KeyName
4. SecurityGroupIds
5. SubnetId
and please check this cloudformation doc on EC2 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html